# How can i get value of textfield when user go to next textfiled in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
return Container(
    width: (screenWidth / 2) - 45,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        LightText(
          text: widget.labelText,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
        ),
        Container(
            height: 24,
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),
            child: Theme(
                data: ThemeData(hintColor: lightGrey),
                child: TextField(
                  inputFormatters: [
                    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                    CurrencyInputFormatter(),
                  ],
                  enabled: widget.enableVal,
                  controller: widget.controllerText,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      contentPadding:
                          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3.0)),
                ))),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please formate your code and please do write some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onChanged` event of the Textfield to get the data whenever it changed.

Here is how you can do this.

```dart
    String someData;
```

```dart
    onChanged: (data) {
      //data is your current value of the textfield.
      someData = data;
    },
```

Using it you will always have a Data of the TextField.

**Edit**

You can also use `onSubmitted` event too to get the result you want.

```
TextField(
  onSubmitted: (data) {},
),
```

Comment: not onchange i want final value of textfield when user done with editing of value @ibhavikmakwana

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextEditingController` for this. Pseudo code sample:

```dart
    TextEditingController _controller;
    ...
    TextField(
       controller: _controller,
    ),
    ...

    void _someMethod(){
      String text = _controller.text;
    }
```

For listening the changes between focuses check this out: [Focus and text fields](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus)

```dart
    FocusNode _focus;
    ...
    TextField(
        focus: _focus;
    )
    ...

    void check(){
        if(_focus.hasFocus){
          // insert handling
        }
    }
```

I think there won't the best answer, until you check documentation by yourself.
[Handle changes to a text field](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes)

Comment: yes, it's working but i want value of textfield when focuse change to another textfield

Comment: Okay, I see. Sorry, I didn't understand your issue right)